# websocket КЛИЕНТ на PHP

Tags: php, websocket, client

Всем привет, читал про вебсокеты, понятно как сделать сервер, понятно как использовать объект жс websocket для связи с этим сервером, а КАК использовать PHP в качестве КЛИЕНТА? Я знаю про сокеты как таковые или функцию fsockopen, но каков алгоритм действий именно в качестве клиента? В мануалах написано сначала надо отправить запрос по HTTP, а потом уже происходит соединение по вебсокету - и вот КАК оно происходит я так не понял, на жс браузер делает это автоматически при использовании объекта websocket, а ЧТО надо сделать при использовании PHP?

Comment: `websocket handshake` смотрите в эту сторону) хотя такое делать на php как по мне не очень хороший вариант) получается что клиент на php должен работать как сервер